# Author's Id from wp list authors function

Tags: author, list-authors

I'm new in wordpress. I want to display all author list with its ID. I'm using [`wp_list_authors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors) function but didn't get any author id from the author list. 
So, How can I get Author's ID in listing of all author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
// prepare arguments
$args  = array(
// search only for Authors role
'role' => 'Author',
// order results by display_name
'orderby' => 'display_name'
);
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
// Check for results
if (!empty($authors))
{
    echo '<ul>';
    // loop trough each author
    foreach ($authors as $author)
    {
        // get all the user's data
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
        echo '<li>'.$author->ID.' '.$author_info->first_name.' '.$author_info->last_name.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}
```

For more reference see [this](http://mattvarone.com/wordpress/list-users-with-wp_user_query/).